# JRE Windows 10 Java App Foreign Text is garbled

Tags: java, windows, utf-8

I have a Java application as a JAR file, that extracts text from various places on the web and displays in a list box. The text is extracted in UTF-8 format. On Mac and Linux systems foreign text is displayed perfectly, no matter what the language. On Windows (10) it is garbled as shown in the image:

[image: Improperly displayed text]

It should be shown as foreign characters.

I'm using JRE 1.8. I've tried installing all of the relevant language packs on Windows, but this has done nothing to fix the problem. (BTW: how do I tell Windows to install ALL language packs, rather than having to select them one at a time?)

I've tried running from `cmd` prompt with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` but it does nothing.

Without changing the code of the Java application, how can I tell the system to display the text correctly? Again, it works fine in Mac and Linux, just Windows bombs out.

This is a Swing program.

Comment: Is this a Swing program?

Comment: Yes it is a Swing program.

Comment: From what I can tell further, it seems that the font is not available to the JVM.